# parse from xml webservice contain only a string

Tags: android

I got the next problem 
I have an xml webservice contain only a string example:
You enter Invalis data 
I wanna read this string to my app. 
my code was working perfect but suddnly it start to return an html code not the string whic i want :( 
here is my code:

```
try {

    String xx;

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
;


    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(urlString);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),
            8);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        xx = stringBuilder.toString();
        }



    inputStream.close();


    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.print("UnsupportedEncodingException: " + e);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.err.print("ClientProtocolException: " + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("IOException: " + e);
    }
```

so pleas if any one can help !!!

Comment: We could help you if only you'll tell us what is happening ? Is an exception thrown ? What is the value of xx ?

Comment: no exceptions the problem with output xx is the string which returnd from the service

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Please make an effort ! Edit your question with the xx output value...